# Python - filling a drop down list with selected object's details

Tags: python

I'm developping an add on to transform 2D plans made of vertices to walls (I extrude them then apply a solidifier modifier). It works great, using a string input to  specify a vertex group, but I'd like to have a drop down list to select the vertex group I want, so it has to be dynamic... But it's where I'm stuck : I know the logic to fetch the vertex groups from the mesh, and obtain the selected item in the drop down list, but how do I make the dropdown dynamic based on the object I selected ? Where do I put the code ?

Here's what I came up with.

**init**.py extract (i removed the registration part of the UI and operator classes for simplicity and readability) :

```
# Drop down list, using enum. As an example, 'sphere' the value, 'Sphere' is the displayed label in the list
# This one is fixed, but need to be dynamic
vgl = bpy.props.EnumProperty(name = 'Vertex Group',
    items = [('sphere', 'Sphere', '8x4 edges'),
             ('ring', 'Ring', '24 vertices'),
             ('square', 'Square', ''),
             ('triangle', 'Triangle', ''),
             ('bidirection', 'Bidirection', ''),
             # etc.
             ])

def register():
    setattr(bpy.types.Scene, 'VERTEX_GROUP_LIST', vgl)

def unregister():
    delattr(bpy.types.Scene, 'VERTEX_GROUP_LIST')
```

UI part :

```
# Build the UI Layout
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel

# Infos about the new panel
class UI_PT_BebWallE(Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "Wall It !"
    bl_category = "Beb WallE"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # Need this if some controls display the selected object's property
        object = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(context.scene, 'VERTEX_GROUP_LIST')
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("object.wall_it",   text= "Wall It !")
```

Operator Part :

```
import bpy, bmesh

class WallIt(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Wall the vertices"""
    bl_idname = "object.wall_it"
    bl_label = "Wall the vertices"

    # Display the menu if the selected is object and in object mode
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.object
        if obj is not None:
            return True
        return False
        
    def execute(self, context):        # execute() is called when running the operator.
        # Get the parameters
        # Values got from the props defined in __init__.py and declared in the UI_beb_ui.py
        VERTEX_GROUP_LIST = context.scene.VERTEX_GROUP_LIST

        print(VERTEX_GROUP_LIST)
```

Clicking the button will display the value of what was selected in my UI. This is the basis of what I want. The only thing missing is : how do I make the contents of the drop down list dynamic, based on the mesh I'm currently selecting ?

Comment: it should be `vgl : bpy.props.EnumProperty` and use `update` argument of `bpy.props.EnumProperty`

Comment: I tried using the update argument, but as far as I tested, but it only triggers when I'm selecting an element in the drop down list. I'd like to have the list updated when I select a new mesh for instance. Also, replacing vgl = bpy.props.EnumProperty by vgl : bpy.props.EnumProperty does not work (the drop down list is not displayed at all)